Хотя знаете что? Запятые в этом предложении
Нужны ли запятые в этом преложении?

Хотя(,) знаете(,) что?


Правильно:
Хотя знаете что?
Пояснение
Знаете что — устойчивое выражение, запятых нет.
Используется в значении: Хотя вот что.
Ответы Справочной службы
№ 281760. Нужна ли запятая в предложении: "А знаешь что?" Спасибо. ОТВЕТ. Запятая не нужна.
Обсуждение на форуме  Пунктуация вопроса "знаешь что?"
